# does this merge sort use O(1) extra space?

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort, space-complexity

Just for my clarification, constant space means O(1) space, right? 
Anyway, here is a code i have written, please tell me if it uses O(1) space.

```
void mergeSort() { 
    ListNode merge = this.head;
    this.head = mergeSort(merge);
}

ListNode mergeSort(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null)
        return head;

    ListNode slow = head; ListNode fast = head.next; 
    while(fast!=null && fast.next !=null) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    ListNode left = head; ListNode right = slow.next;
    slow.next = null;
    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);
    return merge(left, right);
}

ListNode merge(ListNode L, ListNode R) {
    if(L==null) return R;
    if(R==null) return L;
    ListNode h = null;
    if(L.val <= R.val )){
        h = L;
        h.next = merge(L.next, R);
    } else {
        h = R;
        h.next = merge(L, R.next);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Top down merge sort uses O(log(n)) stack space. You can use [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists), which uses a small (25 to 32) fixed size array of references to internal working lists, and would be considered O(1) space. The bottom up approach would be faster by some constant amount, but remain at O(n log(n)) time complexity.